# Objective-C syntax in doxygen markdown pages

Tags: objective-c, markdown, doxygen, documentation-generation, code-documentation

So I am trying to have a documentation guide page for my doxygen generated documentation documentation for my objective-c project, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~{.m}
/**
 This is the private interface of class.
*/
@interface GeneralClass ()
@end
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The issue is that the @interface causes doxygen to try to make an interface for a page instead of just outputting the markdown syntax highlighting for objective-c. Is there a way around this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Also won't read the doxygen style comment. So I am looking for an escape from the parser to just read it as is.

Comment: My mistake. It is just the commenting not the @ sign.

Comment: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdverbatim

Comment: ^ that is what I found but it doesn't actually fix it. Just changes it to plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you ran into this bug/limitation:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720049

For now I recommend to use the suggested workaround, i.e. use `@code...@endcode` instead.